# How to show progress bar image on server-side submit of action through ASP.Net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have requirement to show progress bar image on submission of any server-side action.

I want to show this image till I get the response back from the server.  **While displaying of this loading image user not allowed making any actions on that page i.e. page will be disabled.**

Can anybody know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to so server-side action via ajax call?

Comment: A  google search turned up this http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Show-progress-bar-on-Button-Click-in-ASPNet.aspx. Is this the kind of thing you are asking about?

Comment: Hi Ashok, code link mentioned by you helps me but I have requirement that I want to disable user actions while loading Image is shown i.e. user not allowed to take any action while previous action is in-progress.

Comment: Take a look at using a modal window which will make the main page inaccessible till the task is complete.

Comment: Check whether you can challenge this requirement. In the Web world, it is common practise and understanding that users can click anywhere at any time. In other words: if your user uploads an image and then clicks somewhere else, e. g. the back button: deal with it ! Don't try to stop this from happening.